# Renaming a database tables and columns bound to asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, rename

I have a database with 6 tables with columns bound to an asp.net project and plenty of datasource queries. I want a simple/easy way to rename the database tables and columns in the asp.net website after renaming it in SQL server.

Comment: Do it by hand, but this time put all your table and column names in a single file with string constants.  Then, changing it again in the future will be a lot easier.

Comment: Yes i know .. but i saw some methods like refactoring daabse with visual studio .. and i didn't understand how it works

Comment: this needs much more information. how are you calling the Sql Database in your application? are you using `SqlCommand` or a `.dbml` or a `.edmx`?

Comment: By sql command and with DataSource Object

Comment: @MikeChristensen I would argue that isn't "easier" at all. The changes should be in the DAL, yes, but not as extrapolated constants in most cases. A schema is a complex beast and the entire structure *is a whole* that must work together, not a collection of names that can be idly swapped.

Comment: @user2864740 - Agreed, `+1` for your answer..

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* "simple" way to do this for ad-hoc access/queries and it must be changed "by hand" - a Find (and manual Replace) can be useful, but *a core problem* faced here is the use of ad-hoc (SQL) queries in Data Sources!

Using such an ad-hoc Data Source is often a *terrible* idea - as discovered this hodgepodge does not allow separations of concerns and is hard to update, much less test.

I recommend factoring the database-related code into a DAL - [Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer), which is *separate* from the UI - and using [GenericDataSource](http://genericdatasource.codeplex.com/) to bridge the two. If a DAL was used, then all the access to said information could be exposed through operations and the queries can be nicely contained in a centralized location.

(Since the current code *must* be manually updated and verified, now might be time to make it more maintainable as well.)